# How do I know if the Stripe payment was charged for testing?

Tags: stripe-payments

The dashboard shows that I correctly recieved the token, but is there anywhere that I can check that shows me if the payment went through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status for test transactions would appear in these logs:

https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments

Hope that helps!